# Node.js: displaying MongoDB results using response.write(), when to execute response.end()

Tags: node.js

I'm writing a simple app using Node.js. I use no frameworks (to understand how it works at a "lower" level).

What I'm trying to do:

When a GET request is sent to '/list', I use my MongoDB connection to do a find(). Then I want to iterate over each of the returned items, and display them using response.write("

" + myItem).

The problem is that I need to execute a response.end() at the end, and I don't know when "the end" will be -- as all my response.write() statements are executed using callbacks.

Here's my code:

```
db.items.find({state: "free"}, function(err, myItems) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("There was an error executing the database query.");
            response.end();
            return;
        }
        else if (myItems){
            myItems.forEach( function(myItem) {
                    res.write("<p>" + myItem.title + "</p>\n");
            });
        }
    res.write("</div>");
    res.end();
}
```

I have the feeling I'm missing an idiomatic way to use callbacks here... What's the clean way to fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: I only see one callback and your end is inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Thats the correct way, your end() will be called at the end of your callback, so after your foreach loop, the function will go on and send the end() method.
Or maybe did I missed the point of your question. But I think not.

Comment: I guess the person asking was thinking forEach is asynchronous?